# Unetbootin - a bootable usb that boots on one pc but not another

Tags: 18.04, unetbootin

I used Unetbootin to create an ubuntu18.04 image. When tested on one laptop, it boots to the Unetbootin menu. But on another, this does not work. I am sure i selected the usb device, but the booting process says

```
Boot Device not found
Please install an operating system on your hard disk
Hard disk - (3f0)
f2 system diagnostics
for more information please visit www.hp.com....
```

What could be the problem and what should I do?

**UPDATE**

Laptop is **Hp Elitebook 840 G4**
Bios version is P78 ver 01.08 10/17/2017

ok so this seems to be a bios problem but i dont know how to configure it properly. I am using an HP laptop, and I have made sure I selected 'legacy support enabled and secureboot disabled', but the boot menu cannot find the usb. I know this because I see the same screen in the boot menu, when either the usb is inserted, or not.

The boot menu looks like below

[image]

And my bios config

[image]

Thanks

**UPDATE 2**

I am trying to do a BIOS update but that needs cable connection. however, my laptop does not have the standard cable socket. Now even that is not possible... can anyone tell me what converter/cable I need to do this:

[image]

Comment: 1. Please tell us more about the computer: Which model is it? 2. Have you checked if the UEFI/BIOS system is up to date (the newest stable version)? 3. Please try some other tool to create a bootable USB drive. I would suggest a cloning tool, for example the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator (in 16.04 LTS or newer), Disks (alias gnome-disks) or [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: thanks i have updated the post adding some info about the laptop and bios. i am now trying to do a bios update using the network option....

Comment: According to my experience of HP Elitebooks Ubuntu should work well, but I have no direct experience of your particular model. It should work to boot from a USB drive **cloned** from the **Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2 LTS** iso file both in UEFI mode and BIOS (legacy) mode, at least with the newest version of the UEFI/BIOS system. Please check at an HP web page that you have the newest version of UEFI/BIOS. Finally, there might be problems with older versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @sudodus thanks. I tried to do an update of bios but it needs network, and my laptop does not ave the standard socket. i wonder if you know anything about this (post updated)? thanks

Comment: I have a Lenovo of approximately the same generation, and it it possible to plug in a standard ethernet plug (RJ-45) into it (the bottom part can move downwards). Please try that :-)

Comment: By the way, Unetbootin does not clone. Have you tried with a cloned USB drive yet?

Comment: oh thanks i didnt realise that about the socket, well not a kind of design that i like tbh :) i am now updating the bios... I did not try a cloned usb, but the one that done by unetbootin managed to boot my lenovo laptop, not the hp one. hence I wondered if it was the bios problem rather than the usb...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127279/discussion-between-sudodus-and-ziqi).

Comment: On my EliteBook I press F9 to select boot drive. I have had best luck using **mkusb** to create Persistent USB's. You can install mkusb to the drive you made with UNetbootin. I much prefer mkusb to UNetbootin.